# Java runtime using cmd commands

Tags: java, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am writing a tool to simplify launching a program that needs to be run in command line. I am having the problem with windows 8 and xp where I need to run the command C:\Program Files (x86)\Juniper Networks\Network Connect\ncluancher.exe  + ....Now for some reason in windows 7 the nclauncher is found but not in windows 8 I keep getting the error Could not locate C:\Program. Or Invalid program arguments have been specified.

```
String version_Number = getProgramVersion();
        String url_Location = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Juniper Networks\\Network Connect "
            + version_Number + "\\nclauncher" + "\"";
        String[] location = {url_Location + " -url " + URL + " -u "
            + user_Name + " -p " + pass_Word + "  -r S1AD"};
        // Location of network connect specified.
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(location);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            pr.getInputStream()));
```

Is there any way to make this more universal to xp,win 7 and 8 ? Would A process builder work better for what I am trying to do.

What I found that could work is using the short hand command line method , by this I mean typing C:\Progra~2

Answer (score 0):

identify the os type and use different path for each OS.

Comment: The path should be the exact same, seems it is a parsing issue.

Comment: Have you tried making successful call to windows 8 with some other path and program which is outside program files?. Also verfify the username/pwd are correct.